# How to scale worker roles based on a Queue Length

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

I have a Worker Role that is monitoring a Queue for incoming job. If jobs are arriving faster than they are processed and the queue starts growing in length I want to spin up additional instances of the worker role. I have two questions.
i) Is this a good way to scale in the sense should I be spinning up more instances or should I just manage this with threads somehow.
ii) is there a way to make this configurable without code i.e spin up a new process every time the QueueLength hits a configurable Max and kills off processes when the queue shrinks OR do I need to write a monitoring process that polls Queue Length every so often and makes some decisions about how many process to keep going

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Auto Scaling feature supports scaling based on queue length (Number of messages in a queue). Please see this link for more details on how you can accomplish it: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/cloud-services-how-to-scale/#autoscale